# How to set focus on next component?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, focus

How can I set focus on next component in the form? For example:

        `Button button1 = new Button("Button1");
        button1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                button1.???
            }
        });`

I dont know what next components are, and I dont want to know.
In a hard way I would need to check if next components exist. Next step is check if they are focusable or not. For example next component maight be a button (or other input), but it could be placed in <table><tbody><tr><td>**<button>**</td></tr></tbody></table> so i would need to do that in recursive way.
Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all your components into an array, then figure out where you are in the array and set the focus on the next item in the array.

array[x].setFocus(true);

You'll need to create the array at startup, but otherwise you'll have control over the order of the items no matter what their layout is in the document.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about such solution, but I was hoping that there is another way.